# clang-format normalized line endings

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format

Is it possible to make clang-format normalize line endings to make the coherent in the entire project?

Like this:

```
int main() \n
{\r\n
     return 0;\n
}\r\n
```

would be formatted to:

```
int main() \n
{\n
     return 0;\n
}\n
```

Comment: `git` can do that when you commit.

Comment: @Lehks please read for yourself: https://reviews.llvm.org/D19031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you soppost to commit your code with git, you have a solution.

Optionally, you can configure the way Git manages line endings on a per-repository basis by configuring a special .gitattributes file.

Here's an example .gitattributes file.

Declare files that will always have CRLF line endings on checkout:

```
*.sln text eol=crlf
```

Further information can be find in this [link](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/)

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Clang-Format version 16, you can specify the line endings to write in each file you format.  For example, you could add the following to your `.clang-format` file:

```
# Set EOL to LF unconditionally
LineEnding: LF
```

Clang-Format 16 and newer also offer options to honor the prevailing line endings in each file you are formatting.  For example:

```
# Set EOL to LF unless CR+LF is predominant
LineEnding: DeriveLF
```

For other `LineEnding` options such as `CRLF` see [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#lineending) in the latest Clang-Format documentation.

Source files for LLVM 16.0.0-rc2 -- including the `clang` source, which includes Clang-Format in folder `clang/tools/clang-format` -- is currently available via [the LLVM repository on GitHub](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases).  I do not know when a general release of Clang-Format 16 or newer will occur.